# Symfony make:entity and Single Table Inheritance issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Symfony version: 4.4.x / Doctrine: 2.6.x

I use `make:entity --regenerate` command in Symfony console to generate getters/setters for my classes. I am getting a particular issue with single table inherited classes. Despite the parent table having all the variables and properties declared, `make:entity` ends up creating private variables and methods in inherited table.

```
///Class InfoItem
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="item_type", type="string", length=20)
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"uom"="Uom"})
*/
abstract class InfoItem{
  /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    * @var integer 
    */    
    protected $id;   

   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $code;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(?string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }    
}

///Class Uom
/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Uom extends InfoItem
{
}
```

Now when I run `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`, the command results in an unnecessary modification of Uom class.

```
class Uom{

    private $id;
    private $code;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(?string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And if you run the `make:entity` command again, it results in an error:

```
Compile Error: Access level to App\Entity\Uom::$id must be protected (as in class App\Entity\InfoItem) or weaker
```

Please advise. This is proving to be a major headache.

Comment: Answer has been given below by Youssef, but wanted to point out that you should not declare "DiscriminatorMap". [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html): `If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated automatically. The automatically generated discriminator map contains the lowercase short name of each class as key.` - It also makes no sense for the parent class to know all of the classes that implemented it (like interfaces need not know about class implementations).

Comment: Change `private $id` to `protected $id` in Uom class

Answer (score 0):

Yo should declare the properties of the parents as `private`. In your case, `$id` and `$code` should be `private` and not `protected`.